# How can I aggregate the documents in an array instead of in a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following collection **cidade** on my MongoDB database:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 0, 
    "nome" : "CIDADE0", 
    "qtdhab" : 1231043 
}
```

So, here's what I want to do. I'm trying to do the equivalent of this SQL query in MongoDB:

```
SELECT MAX(QTDHAB) FROM CIDADE WHERE QTDHAB <= (SELECT AVG(QTDHAB) FROM CIDADE);
```

Basically, I want the **biggest** value of the field **qtdhab** from the collection **cidade** which follows the condition of being **lower than the average value** of the same field **qtdhab** on the same collection **cidade**. So, I have mapped this into 3 queries, like this:

```
var resultado = db.cidade.aggregate({"$group": {"_id": null, "avgHab": {"$avg": "$qtdhab"}}}).toArray()
var resultado2 = db.cidade.find({qtdhab: {$lte: resultado[0].avgHab}}).toArray()
resultado2.aggregate({"$group": {"_id": null, "maxHab": {"$max": "$qtdhab"}}})
```

The problem is, as I found out the hard way, that there is no **.aggregate** method for an array such as **resultado2**, so the last query returns an error. Is there any other way for me to get the **biggest value** for the field **qtdhab** out of this array of documents that was generated by these 2 queries?

Comment: We cannot see your document, but you want to basically do something like get the first results from each array and then work out some values from that. But first you need to deconstruct the array. So see [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), or at least post something here people can work with.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have updated the post with the document structure.

Comment: What does that document structure have to do with arrays? I see no array there. Or is that the array element within the document? I think the actual document containing the array is the imporatant part here.

Comment: There is no document with an array. The arrays I refer to are the ones generated by the queries.

Comment: There are no arrays generated by queries, only cursors. Old versions of MongoDB return aggregation results in arrays, and also the `.distinct()` and `.mapReduce()` methods. Calling `.toArray()` returns an array from a cursor. But otherwise there are no arrays as results. Please be more clear about what you are doing in your question.

Comment: Yes, if you read the code I have provided, you can see that I am using the **.toArray()** method to return an array from the result of the queries. However, that's not what the question is about. It is about how to return the **MAX** value in the array **resultado2**, which was generated by the method **.toArray()** called from the second query that I listed in the question.

Comment: So how on earth did it never occur to you to call `.toArray()` on the aggregation result?

Comment: Because there is no aggregate method for an array, that's the whole point of the question. The last line of the code doesn't work, because such a method does not exist for an array. What I'm asking here is an equivalent method that does the same thing as the aggregate method for an array.

Comment: Anyway, no need to worry, the question was already answered by the guy below. Thanks for your time, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using only one query(aggregation):

```
db.cidade.aggregate([
    /*find the avg and keep also the aggregated field*/
    {"$group": {
        "_id": null, 
        "qtdhab" : {"$push" :"$qtdhab"},
        "avgHab": {"$avg": "$qtdhab"}
    }},
    /*unwind the array*/
    {$unwind: "$qtdhab"},
    /*get the max from the fields less than the avg*/
    {"$group": {
        "_id": null, 
        "res" : {"$max" : {$cond :[{$lte :["$qtdhab", "$avgHab"]}, "$qtdhab", null]} },
    }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I'm not familiar with $cond though, so I'll read the documentation to understand your code before testing it. I'll post a comment here when I'm done.